# Error on installation with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
I have created the following package.json
   {
  "name": "garima",
  "description": "garima app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "*",
    "mongoose": "*"
  }
}
```

I get the following error on running

> npm install
>
> kerberos@0.0.7 install /home/admin/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
>   (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

I am trying to install MongoDb with node.js.I am new to node.js please suggest what changes have to be made to package.json.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package.json is fine, you could remove the "mongodb" part because that is a dependency from mongoose anyway but it doesn't hurt to have it in there either.

It fails on building the dependency "kerberos" (https://github.com/christkv/kerberos)

Try to type in `npm install kerberos` and post the output here. If it's just showing something like node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log show us whatever is in the file "builderror.log".